# Spring mvc with hibernate @OneToMany relationship mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYIEp.jpg)I have two table one is Credit and second is Debit. I want @OneToMany relationship. in credit table only single row of data and In debit table multiple row of data

**Credit table:**

1. cid
2. openingBalance
3. date
4. debittotal
5. drawertotal
6. debittotalplusdrawertotal
7. todaybusiness

   all row of only single row data

**Debit table:**

1. did
2. amounnt
3. description

   amount and description multiple data add

I am using Spring mvc with hibernate project structure is just like below

1. controller
2. entity
3. dao
4. daoImpl
5. service
6. serviceImpl

How to create enitiy with @OneToMany Relationship and when I save that data then all data will save at time into two table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Cascade persist for this.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="credit", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
List<Debit> debits;
```

and then in your dao:

```
Credit credit = new Credit(......);
credit.setDebits(/*the list of debits*/)
entityManager.persist(credit);
```

or if you're using springdata jpa :

```
repository.save(credit);
```

Comment: can you provide me proper explanation credit and debit is model

Comment: I has try this but is is save only one table of data

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1279932/Spring-MVC-with-hibernate-onetomany-relationship-m

Comment: 1) on this line :   creditdebit.setDebit(credit.getDebit());   , are sure getDebit return a non empty list ?   2) you need to remove mappedBy if you have an unidirectional association.

Comment: 1) on this line I have try to print in console credit.getDebit() is return null 2) mappedBy remove

Comment: credit.getDebit() must contain the list of debit you want to store in the database.

Comment: Yes, multiple column amount and description I want to store when I do session.save(credit); then automatically debit of all data save into the two table

Comment: I has a also add image at the starting point of my questions for clarifying easy